# Access denied for user 'root' (using password: NO)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, mariadb

This is my docker-compose file, everytime I run the docker-compose up command I get the error specified in the title. I have tried running docker-compose config and everything matches.

```
 version: "3.8"                                                                          
    services:                                                                               
      phedon-service:                                                                       
        build: .                                                                            
        restart: always                                                                     
        ports:                                                                              
          - "8080:8080"                                                                     
        networks:                                                                           
          - phedon                                                                          
        depends_on:                                                                         
          - phedon_db                                                                       
        env_file:                                                                           
          - .env                                                                            
      phedon_db:                                                                            
        image: "mariadb:10.6"                                                               
        container_name: mariadb                                                             
        restart: always                                                                     
        healthcheck:                                                                        
          test: [ "CMD", "mariadb-admin", "--protocol", "tcp" ,"ping" ]                     
          timeout: 3m                                                                       
          interval: 10s                                                                     
          retries: 10                                                                       
        ports:                                                                              
          - "3307:3306"                                                                     
        networks:                                                                           
          - phedon                                                                          
        environment:                                                                        
          -MYSQL_DATABASE: "phedondb"                                                       
          -MYSQL_USER: "root"                                                               
          -MYSQL_PASSWORD: "12345"                                                          
          -MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "12345"                                                                                      
        env_file:                                                                           
        - .env                                                                              
    networks:                                                                               
       phedon:
```

Comment: Why use `.env` file and `environment` for `mariadb` service? Provide single configuration.

Comment: Changed it and got the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. your `services.db.environment` must be a mapping, not a list.
2. we can omit the root user password with `MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD`

   ```yaml
   db:
     image: "mariadb:10.6"                                                               
     container_name: mariadb                                                             
     restart: always                                                                     
     healthcheck:                                                                        
       test: [ "CMD", "mariadb-admin", "--protocol", "tcp" ,"ping" ]                     
       timeout: 3m                                                                       
       interval: 10s                                                                     
       retries: 10                                                                       
     ports:                                                                              
       - "3333:3306"
     environment:                                                                        
       MYSQL_DATABASE: "phedondb"                                                       
       MYSQL_USER: "phedon"                                                               
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: "12345"
       MARIADB_ALLOW_EMPTY_ROOT_PASSWORD: true
   ```
3. If you like to use the root password
   For the admin ping command, we've to provide the password for the DB server. This can be done in different ways.

   - Using the `MYSQL_PWD` environment var.
   - Using the `-p` flag in the docker CLI
   - Creating some credentials file

   ```yaml
   services:
     db:
     image: "mariadb:10.6"                                                               
     container_name: mariadb                                                             
     restart: always                                                                     
     healthcheck:                                                                        
       test: [ "CMD-SHELL", "mysqladmin ping" ]                     
       timeout: 3m                                                                       
       interval: 10s                                                                     
       retries: 10                                                                       
     ports:                                                                              
       - "3333:3306"
     environment:                                                                        
       MYSQL_DATABASE: "phedondb"                                                       
       MYSQL_USER: "phedon"                                                               
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: "12345"
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "12345"
       MYSQL_PWD: "12345"
   ```

Comment: I wrote the first version, it worked!